# Compare Specific Points of Line Features in two Feature Classes using FeatureClassToNumPyArray

Tags: arcpy, geometry, cursor, numpy

I am looking to compare the first and last point between features in two different feature classes.  The features share a common ID.  My thought was to create two arrays via [FeatureClassToNumPyArray](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.4/analyze/arcpy-data-access/featureclasstonumpyarray.htm).  Then combined them.  There is some magic in FeatureClassToNumPyArray where you can use tokens to pull out different geometry parts, but there isnt a token for first or last point.  [Dan Patterson](https://community.esri.com/blogs/dan_patterson/2017/10/15/to-points) offers some context, but doesnt address pulling out specific points from a line geometry.

You use the  ‘explode to points’ parameter and get the individual points, but only as additional rows and I don’t know if the point order (to determine first and last) is maintained, particularly if I was to pivot the table to it all in one row.

Here is the outline of the final array (or dictionary or list of list etc.) be based on:

[ID,FX1, FY1, FX2, FY2, LX1, LY1, LX2, LY2, DFX, DFY, DLX, DLY]

where F is first point, L is last point, 1&2 are the two feature classes, XY are the coordinates, D is the delta between the two.

The only other way I know to do this is using nested searchcursors and loops to loop through each feature while cracking option the geometry and comparing.

Comment: What makes you think that vertices order is not maintaned? I suggest using add geometry tool, that will populate most of the fields you need.

Comment: The tool you mentioned is a script tool which is even, better.  I can crack it open and see.

Comment: @FelixIP I think your comment is a suitable answer. Perhaps add a link to the description/help of the tool and add below, if you would like.

Comment: Please answer your own question, it's legit. My PC is undergoing maintenance.